# Xcode : I need help to solution for upload testflight

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to upload, then i validate my project before i upload, xcode tell me about this so what a alternative solution for upload testflight, did i buy new macbook m1?

[[image: pict]

Comment: try just to update xcode to 13.2 or latest to this heres a link for list xcodes https://xcodereleases.com/

Answer (score 0):

You must update Xcode to version 13, in order to upload apps to AppStore.

Here you can read the official news: [Official News](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=2t1chhp3)